# Piso S1 adb works but fastboot doesn't. Linux

Tags: android, adb, udev, ubuntu-12.10, fastboot

lsusb of the device in developer mode (ADB connects fine).

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 2207:0010  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64 
  idVendor           0x2207 
  idProduct          0x0010 
  bcdDevice            2.22
  iManufacturer           2 samsung
  iProduct                3 SGH-I777
  iSerial                 4 YNNFP969J2
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
```

lsusb -v device in bootloader mode.

```
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 2207:300a  
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.01
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x2207 
  idProduct          0x300a 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
```

/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2207", ATTR{idProduct}=="300a" , MODE="0600"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2207", ATTR{idProduct}=="0010" , MODE="0600"
```

fastboot devices is empty...
by the way i'm using Xubuntu 12.10.
I will apreciate your help.
Sebastian.

Comment: please provide full `lsusb -v` output. if it's too long - put it on pastebin

Comment: also with `MODE="0600"` you need to run fastboot (and lsusb for that matter) as root. or change that to `MODE="0666"`

Comment: @AlexP. I think you should put as an answer that we have to run fastboot as root.. That worked for me!. Thanks!